# Modify a string in a list - at a particular index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that contains some strings:

```
x = ["james", "john", "robert", "michael", "william", "david", "richard", "charles", "joseph", "thomas", "christopher"]
```

I want to delete the first letter of every item in the list, **on the condition that the first letter of the item is "j".** The only items in the list to be changed are the ones that start with the letter "j", the rest stay the same.

The Desired Output should be like this:

```
x = ["ames", "ohn", "robert", "michael", "william", "david", "richard", "charles", "oseph", "thomas", "christopher"]
```

I tried various traditional `for loops` and I did not get the desired result. I have a problem accessing a string in a list, at a particular index!

This is just an example, the list I have contains tens of thousand items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.startswith` to check if string starts with `j` and then use slicing to remove it.

**Ex:**

```
x = ["james", "john", "robert", "michael", "william", "david", "richard", "charles", "joseph", "thomas", "christopher"]
print([i[1:] if i.startswith("j") else i for i in x])
```

**Output:**

```
['ames', 'ohn', 'robert', 'michael', 'william', 'david', 'richard', 'charles', 'oseph', 'thomas', 'christopher']
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. It would be better if this solution allows updating the list without creating a new variable. However, I am satisfied with your answer! Cheers!

Comment: It does not create a new variable...you can do `x = [i[1:] if i.startswith("j") else i for i in x]`

Comment: Indeed, it seems you're are right. I didn't notice that you used the variable x throughout your answer instead of the variable I supplied mylist. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lstrip`, i.e.

```
[i.lstrip('j') for i in x]
#['ames', 'ohn', 'robert', 'michael', 'william', 'david', 'richard', 'charles', 'oseph', 'thomas', 'christopher']
```

Comment: I don't know, it might work for this particular list, but suppose we have a "j" in the middle of the string! We don't want to change that, only at the beginning. Like "james" becomes "ames" but "elijah" stays the same.

Comment: @AkbarHussein it will remain same `lstrip` will only remove leading `j`

Comment: It will only remove the leading `j`.

Comment: you are right, I tried your answer and it works, I am very new to python :)

Comment: @AkbarHussein, It's ok. So am I :)

Answer (score 1):

Optimal approach would be to use `lstrip`.

```
prob =["james", "john", "robert", "michael", "william", "david", "richard", "charles", "joseph", "thomas", "christopher"]
prob = [a_prob.lstrip('j') for a_prob in prob]
print(prob)
```

Output:

```
['ames', 'ohn', 'robert', 'michael', 'william', 'david', 'richard', 'charles', 'oseph', 'thomas', 'christopher']
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer?

Comment: Yes it's almost same @Sotos, moreover i didn't saw your answer before posting mine.

Comment: Your answer seems to work, I didn't notice it first. Thanks for your help. I am curious if it would work if I have a string within a list that's within a list. Let's say: x = [[90, "james"], [92, "john"], [92, "michael"], [90, "ali"]]

Comment: That calls for a different question. In that case you have list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

itemgetter used to get value based on an index from iterable.
refer this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = itemgetter(0)
print([val[1:] if data(val) == 'j' else val for val in x])
>>> ['ames', 'ohn', 'robert', 'michael', 'william', 'david', 'richard', 'charles', 'oseph', 'thomas', 'christopher']
```